# Send data from contents script to main.js in Firefox SDK extension with ports

Tags: firefox, sdk, port

I'm developing simple FF SDK Add-on, my current goal is to pass hooked link from webpage to Add-on's code and open Add-on's tab.

Manual https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port tells me that using self.port.emit()& self.port.on() is an appropriate way for this. self.port.emit() called in my content script embedded into webpage by PageMod but in main.js I've stumbled with "self.port is undefined" in the window where cfx run is running. Below is snipped:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*", // <- this tell firefox to attach the following
                //    content script to all web pages
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url("js/script.js")
});



self.port.on("gotLink", function(myAddonMessagePayload) {
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
  url: self.data.url("page.html"),
});
});
```

probably self.port is not that self that got from var self = require("sdk/self")? then, how do I get right 'self' to listen recieve data from content script?

Answer (score 0):

`self.port.on` works in the content script, where as you'll need a worker object (see [using port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port) and [worker object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/content_worker)) to send a message to the content script. So in main.js: `worker.port.on` and `worker.port.emit` and in the content script `self.port.on` and `self.port.emit`.

Answer (score 0):

1st, You are right about: "self.port is not that self that got from var self = require("sdk/self")". Refer to:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self.

> Note that the self module is completely different from the global self object accessible to content scripts, which is used by a content script to communicate with the add-on code.

2nd, "addon script" can communicate with " content script" like this:

```
var worker = require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
  contentScript: "self.port.emit('onTextSelected', window.getSelection().toString());"
});

worker.port.on("onTextSelected", function (text){
  console.log("onTextSelected: "+ text);
  selectionText = text;
});
```

You can do the same way in the "PageMode".